# Geometric progression with negative and positive exponentiation

Tags: sequences-and-series

How this sum can be performed if not with the use of usual formula $S_n=a_1(q^n-1)/(q-1)$?

$${1\over6}\sum_{n=-2}^3(0.5e^{-jk\pi/3})^n$$

Comment: Is the sum over $k = -2, \ldots, 3$ or $n = -2, \ldots, 3$?

Comment: the sum is over n

Comment: So, why do you want something other than that formula?

Comment: Since you know there are exactly six terms in the series, you could just write out each one explicitly with five $+$ signs to add them together. But it's still not clear how that would be better than using the well-known formula.

Comment: @DavidK  But the well-known formula uses non negative exponentiation, doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "usual formula" for summing a finite geometric series
assumes an arbitrary first term $a_1$, 
followed by terms $a_1q^p$ for positive integer exponents $p$. 
In your case, you get the first term by plugging $n=-2$ into the expression
to the right of the $\sum$ symbol.

The $n$ under the $\sum$ symbol in your question is *not* the $n$ 
that you often find written in the "usual formula".
Perhaps it might help if you write the "usual formula" as

$$ S_m = a_1 \frac{q^m - 1}{q - 1} $$

where $m$ is the number of terms in the series.

Now take another look at
$$\sum_{n=-2}^3(0.5e^{-jk\pi/3})^n.$$

What is the first term, $a_1$? What is the ratio, $q$? 
How many terms are there (that is, what is $m$)?

Comment: all p terms are not positive (in this case) , so 2 first terms shouldn't be ignored?

Comment: Again, the number $n$ under the $\sum$ does not match anything in the "usual formula". You have six terms, $a_1 + a_1q + a_1q^2 + a_1q^3 + a_1q^4 + a_1q^5$ ($p = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ for the last five terms). The term $a_1$ occurs when $n=-2$, and $a_1q$ occurs when $n = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

The general expression is $$\sum_{n=a}^b x^n=\frac{x^a-x^{b+1}}{1-x}$$ You can also write $$\sum_{n=a}^b x^n=x^a\sum_{n=0}^{b-a} x^{n-a}=x^a\sum_{m=0}^{b-a} x^{m}=x^a\frac{1-x^{-a+b+1}}{1-x}=\frac{x^a-x^{b+1}}{1-x}$$

Comment: Bon soir mon amie!  +1 - Mark

Comment: Pardon mon francais.  J'ai oublier.  So the correct spelling is "ami?"  Or is amie feminine and ami masculine?

Comment: Cheers mon ami!